# Python: GUI for continuously running script

Tags: python, user-interface

I am writing a script which will run continuously on a computer. As it has to run on a computer without python installation, I am planning to convert it to executable. I also want to have a GUI to start and stop this application but I don't want this GUI to be opened all the time. I mean if the GUI is closed, I don't want the executable to stop running. It should stop only if user presses stop button on GUI. This GUI is just a interface for users to start and stop the executable.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Check for example http://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/

Comment: Can you provide some info on what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Totem: How is kivy going to help with this?

Comment: Well, yeah, but it doesn't help you make the background program, or communicate between the gui and the background program, which is the part he seems to be asking about.

Comment: @Totem: I am actually stuck. I added a GUI to my continuously running application but after I start the application, my GUI gets stuck. I tried to use multitreading. It solved the first problem, but as soon as I close GUI, my script also stops. But now I am getting some idea about having two separate applications. I still have to figure out how to get them to interact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is to have two separate programs: a backgrounder/daemon/agent/service that just chugs along in the background detached from user input and output, and a GUI program to control it. A nice advantage of this design is that you can also have a command-line program to control it, if you ever want to ssh in remotely, or control it from a script.

---

The traditional Unix way of handling this is to use a [daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) designed like a system service (even if it's run like a normal user): it writes its pid to a file when it starts up, and the control program reads that file and sends a signal to the pid that it finds to kill it.

So, the control program has functions something like this:

```
def is_running():
    try:
        with open(PID_PATH) as f:
            pid = int(f.read())
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def stop():
    with open(PID_PATH) as f:
        pid = int(f.read())
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)

def start():
    subprocess.check_call(DAEMON_PATH)
```

Of course in real life, you'll want some better error handling. Also, which signal you use depends on whether you want the daemon to die hard and instantly, or to gracefully shut down. And so on.

---

An alternative is to have the background process listen on a socket—whether TCP with a known port, or a Unix socket with a known filename—and communicate with it that way. This allows you to do fancier things that just start and stop.

---

On Windows, the details aren't quite the same, but you can do something similar.

---

Finally, Windows, OS X, and various linux distros also all have platform-specific ways of wrapping this kind of thing up at a higher level, so you might want to build a Windows Service, LaunchAgent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @abarnert.I used your method and converted your code for windows. Please see below my solution which works. It's starting and stopping helloworld.exe. I have removed error handling to keep it simple.

```
import subprocess
import time

def startprocess():
    #start helloworld.exe
    process = subprocess.Popen(['helloworld.exe'])
    #Write down the prog id into a file for later use
    f = open('progid.txt','w')
    f.writelines(str(int(process._handle)))
    f.close()

def endprocess():    
    f = open('progid.txt','r')
    progid  = int(f.read())
    f.close()
    # Kill the process using pywin32
    import win32api
    win32api.TerminateProcess(progid, -1)

startprocess()
time.sleep(60) #wait for 60 second before kill
endprocess()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're killing the background process 60 seconds after you stop it. Also, for writing a single string, you want `f.write`, not `f.writelines`. (`f.writelines` will assume your string is a sequence, break it down into 1-character sequences, and assume each one already has a newline so it won't add one, so you end up with the same output, but slower, and more likely to get corrupted if someone pulls the plug in the middle.) And finally, you may want to use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))` instead of the current working directory.

Comment: Also, a `with` statement is better than an explicit `close`—besides saving one line of source, it means that if the `read` raises an exception, the file still gets closed. And you shouldn't need `win32api`; `os.kill` should work fine. (See the docs; anything but the special ^C/Break values just calls `TerminateProcess` for you.) But other than those little fiddly details, it all looks good.